# Ошибка про обучении модели

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, opencv

У меня есть скаченные изображения для обучения мой модели. Но когда идёт сам процесс обучения постоянно возникает ошибка:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # RGB image
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-oduouqig\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Как я понял изображение загружается некорректно.
Что можно сделать в этом случае?

Вот код:

```
from imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer

trainer = DetectionModelTrainer()
trainer.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
trainer.setDataDirectory(data_directory=r"C:\rec\data")
trainer.setTrainConfig(object_names_array=["hat","person"], batch_size=10, num_experiments=15, train_from_pretrained_model="pretrained-yolov3.h5")
trainer.trainModel()
```

Comment: Ну какие-то изображения либо пустые, либо не цветные, не знаю. Попробуйте их "вручную" пооткрывать через cv2 и поконвертить. Которые окажутся не годными - уберите из каталога загрузки

Comment: Впринципе я так и делал, но вот файлов у меня много. Есть возможность это всё дело автоматизировать?

Comment: Так можно на питоне это и сделать. Цикл по файлам, ловить исключение и перемещать файлы в другой каталог

Comment: Я прошёлся по всем изображениям в цикле, никаких исключений не поймал. Все картинки цветные и не пустые

Comment: @Maksim а как прошлись? Что делали, укажите конкретно

Comment: С помощью glob зашёл в каталог, используя функцию cv.COLOR_RGBA2RGB проверял, конвертируется ли изображение в формат rgb